# Event machine connection time out handling?

Tags: ruby, eventmachine

What is the standard way of handling TCP connection timeout issues in EventMachine?
The EventMachine::Connection.send_data method does not return a deferrable(Future) So there is no way to check whether send_data method is failed due to TCP connection timeout or for some other reason.

Comment: You need to save state and account for it on errors